# Fetch remote branch into current branch using Git and VS2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I am used to TortoiseGit where I can select `Fetch` and am given the option which branch (remote or local) I want to pull into my current branch. A good example is I might want to fetch the `master` branch into my current working branch to make sure I keep up with what other developers are committing to `master`.

I cannot seem to find this option in Visual Studio 2015. I can merge a remote branch into my local branch (as seen in the screen capture) yet I don't see an option to `Fetch`.

[image]

Comment: Does TortoiseGit actually bring the contents of the remote branch into your local branch?  (That's what it sounds like you're describing but I want to make sure that I understand.)

Comment: It was my understanding that with TortoiseGit if I did a Pull that the changes were brought into the branch. If there were no conflicts then it was automatically commited.

Comment: That would be my understanding, but what does _Fetch_ do in TortoiseGit?

Comment: I thought that `Fetch` would bring down the changes but not `commit` them, even if there were no conflicts. It would be up to me to `commit`